# How can I switch off rustfmt for a region of code instead of a single item?

Tags: rust, rustfmt

[`#[rustfmt::skip]` allows you to skip a "block" of code while formatting](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustfmt/issues/1322), but this requires putting `skip` on each `{}` instead of Clang-style `on/off`

Consider this code:

```rust
fn add(a : i32, b : i32) -> i32 { a + b }
fn sub(a : i32, b : i32) -> i32 { a - b }
```

rustfmt will format this to:

```rust
fn add(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    a + b
}
fn sub(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    a - b
}
```

One needs two `#[rustfmt::skip]` attributes instead of a single `on/off`.

There is a rustfmt option for single-line functions, but this example is for demonstration purposes only. I want to control any possible rustfmt setting in the region.

Answer (score 62):

You could put the functions you do not want to format in a module, tag the entire module with a `#[rustfmt::skip]`, then pull in the items to the parent module with `use`.

```rust
#[rustfmt::skip]
mod unformatted {
    pub fn add(a : i32, b : i32) -> i32 { a + b }
    pub fn sub(a : i32, b : i32) -> i32 { a - b }
}

use unformatted::*;

fn main() {
    dbg!(add(2, 3));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to put all rustfmt_skipped code-blocks into a single file and then record the filename in [`ignore`](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustfmt/?version=v1.5.1&search=#ignore).